# How to share texutes in OpenGL ES 2.0 on AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android-studio, opengl-es, textures, rendering

`Finally, I solved my problem thanks to Columbo.`

I am making a strategy simulation game using AndroidStudio with OpenGL ES 2.0 and having a problem of loading images efficiently. The game was designed to load all images with the start of it and worked well. However, I have tried to load only images that need in each screen as time went by because the game includes many images. But I got the error message `E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)` with blank (black) space at the screen when I tried some changes.

Through Google, I have found some information about the activity, surfaceview, rendering, thread, sharing textures, etc. and tired them. However, any answers didn't work on my app in AndroidStudio and I have no idea what the reason is. The main problem is that when I tried to apply the answers, I don't know where I should exactly put the code and the sample code, mainly related to "egl", expressed with red color meaning error in my AndroidStudio. Below are some examples.

```
1. eglGetCurrentContext()
2. eglCreateContext(mEglDisplay, mEglConfig, sharedContext, contextAttribs);
```

I would like to make my app to work more efficiently. I think sharing texture by another thread is the best solution, but any other solution is fine if it loads images separately at each screen. Please help me with an actual code that can be applied to my app.

### [Explanation about my code]

> initResourceMap() is executed when the screen change from `Intro` to `Map`, and the error message shows up (`E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)`).

```
// 1. Main Activity
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
//GLSurfaceView
private GLSurfaceView mGLSurfaceView;

//Create Activity
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Matrix to create surfaceview    
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    mGLSurfaceView = new MainGLSurfaceView(this, width, height, 1, 1);
    setContentView(mGLSurfaceView);
}
}


// 2. SurfaceView class
class MainGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
//Renderer
private MainGLRenderer mGLRendererMain;

//Creator
public MainGLSurfaceView(MainActivity activity, int width, int height, int stage, int subStage){
    super(activity.getApplicationContext());
    //Create OpenGL ES 2.0 context
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    //Create renderer by using Context to use GLSurfaceView
    mGLRendererMain = new MainGLRenderer(activity, this, width, height);
    setRenderer(mGLRendererMain);
    //Draw if changed RenderMode
    setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
}
}



// 3. Renderer
public class MainGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
// Matrix
private final float[] mMtrxProjection = new float[16];
private final float[] mMtrxView = new float[16];
private final float[] mMtrxProjectionAndView = new float[16];
// Program color, image
private static int mProgramSolidColor;
private static int mProgramImage;
long mLastTime;
// Device's width, height
public static int mDeviceWidth = 0;
public static int mDeviceHeight = 0;
// Main activity
MainActivity mActivity;
Context mContextMain;
Context mContextStory;
// Set screen
ScreenConfig mScreenConfig;

// Creator
public MainGLRenderer(MainActivity activity, MainGLSurfaceView surfaceView, int width, int height){
    mSurfaceView = surfaceView;
    mActivity = activity;
    mContextMain = activity.getApplicationContext();
    mLastTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 100;
    mDeviceWidth = width;
    mDeviceHeight = height;
}

// Create surface view
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig eglConfig){
    mScreenConfig = new ScreenConfig(mDeviceWidth, mDeviceHeight);
    mScreenConfig.setSize(2000, 1200);
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1);
    int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vs_Image);
    int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fs_Image);
    mProgramImage = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgramImage, vertexShader);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgramImage, fragmentShader);
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgramImage);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramImage);

    if(mIsFirstCalled){
        init();
    }
    else {
        initResourceIntro();
        mResourceLoadingMain.setResourceIntro(mSubject, mRyubiIntro, mGwanuIntro,
                mJangbiIntro, mBtnEnter);
        mResourceLoadingMain.setResourceMap(mPanelMap, mCity, mCityName, mRyubiMap, mGwanuMap,
                mJangbiMap, mChochoMap, mHahudonMap, mJanghabMap, mBtnExit);
        mResourceLoadingMain.setResourceGame(mOurForce, mOurForceEnergy, mOurForceWord,
                mEnemyForce, mEnemyForceEnergy, mEnemyForceWord, Map.mLand);
    }
    mIsFirstCalled = false;

    mMoveInputX = 1000;
    mMoveInputY = 600;
}

private void init(){
    initResourceIntro();
    initObject();
    initIntro();
}

private void initResourceIntro(){
    float scale = mContextMain.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    mResourceLoadingMain = new ResourceLoading(mActivity, mContextMain, scale);
    mResourceLoadingMain.initResource();
}

private void initResourceMap(MainActivity activity){
    mSurfaceView.restartRenderer(activity, mDeviceWidth, mDeviceHeight);
    mContextStory = activity.getApplicationContext();
    float scale = mContextStory.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    mResourceLoadingStory = new ResourceLoading(mActivity, mContextStory, scale);
    mResourceLoadingStory.initResource();
}
}
```

Comment: Where is `initResourceMap` called from? Generally if you want to do any OpenGLES stuff, you ought to do it on `GLSurfaceView`'s thread. i.e. Put your texture loading code in `onDrawFrame`. If you need to respond to some system event, then just set a flag and deal with it next time `onDrawFrame` is called.

Comment: Columbo, you are so great. I solved the problem when I exactly did what you mentioned in detail. It's really helpful and I appreciate your help so much!